# What is the recommended way to force a query string array parameter to be treated with style form and explode false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I want my api to accept a query string array parameter in the form `?id=a,b,c,d` as opposed to the standard `?id=a&id=b&id=c`. For this I am following [this excellent blog article](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/07/customizing-query-string-parameter-binding-in-asp-net-core-mvc/).

Side question: Does ASP.NET Core provide built-in providers/attributes for that yet?

My main question however, is about [SwashBuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore):

In short, I'm trying to get a comma-separated parameter (`?p=a,b,c,d`) that is typed as an `IEnumerable<string>`, to show up correctly in the generated Swagger. According to the [specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) it should get `style=form` and `explode=false`. The default here (`style=form` and `explode=true`) matches the asp.net core default. How do I achieve this? Is there an annotation attribute that I can place on the parameter?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? I have the same issue